# Como criar um tema/template WordPress que se atualiza sozinho?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Tem como fazer um tema/template em WordPress, que quando eu faço uma edição nele, ele se atualiza sozinho, sem precisar ficar fazendo upload?

Comment: Isso você resolve com um bom editor. O programa fará upload automático cada vez que se salva um arquivo.

Comment: Se editar no próprio servidor, creio que não vá precisar de upload nunca :)

Comment: Isso é uma pessima prática, é conhecida de "cowboy coding" ou editar arquivos direto no servidor. Se é um site sem importância que vc pode quebrar sem problemas então vai em frente. Se não, desenvolva em ambiente local, teste, depois use o git ou algum outro metodo de deploy para automatizar o processo. O meu editor favorito e que oferece muitas ferramentas de deploy é o PHPStorm.

Answer (score 2):

Sempre será necessário algum tipo de conexão com o servidor remoto para o envio dos arquivos, mas é possível ter uma experiência mais automatizada com um programa de FTP como o [Cyberduck](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/edit) (código aberto). Ele se encarrega de enviar os arquivos automaticamente.

Para pequenas edições funciona bem, mas é sempre bom lembrar que essa é uma prática que deve ser desencorajada para projetos web, de forma geral, pois a edição remota de arquivos traz uma série de problemas para um projeto.

Melhor usar controle de versão e ambientes diferentes de desenvolvimento (assunto para outro tópico).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um editor online, alguns serviços de hospedagem oferecem edição online pelo CPanel, File Editor.

Pode ser uma prática perigosa se alguém tiver acesso ao teu editor online.

Com o FTP/SFTP apesar do atraso na comunicação, mas é mais seguro.